# Load UIWebView from 2nd VC and print it to PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to create a PDF file with a buch of data. The PDF has 7 pages, contains text, images and charts and works fine so far.
Now I have to add a html-table to one of the PDFs pages. In that ViewController I added a WebView and try loading the data in the background, then printing it to the file.
When presenting the ViewController, the WebView does load the page. But I need it to load while not being presented, my current problem is that the UIWebView stays white in the PDF-file: `webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` is not being called.

Code VC1:

```
PDFPage6ViewController *pdf2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PDF6"];
pdf2.controlIdentifier = controlIdentifier;
pdf2.startDate = startDate;
pdf2.endDate = endDate;

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero,nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[pdf2.view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Code PDF2:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self getDataFromDatabase];
}


- (void)getDataFromDatabase {
    /*loading data*/
    [self processData];
}

- (void)processData {
    /*doing some calculations*/
    NSString *html = /*creating the html string*/
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the UIWebView delegate to self?

Comment: Yes, the delegate is set to the 2nd VC

Comment: What about the processData? Does it invoked?

Comment: You have to create PDF at the webViewDidFinishLoad:.

Comment: Yes, it is. If I present the PDF VC the WebView loads the html-table correctly, processData and webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView are then called. If I don't present the VC, processData is called, too. Only the WebView wont load

Comment: I cant create the PDF from the 2nd VC, because there are pages before and after this one. All 7 pages are created from VC1.

Comment: A bit late to the party but I don't think the UIWebView delegate methods get called unless the view is actually presented.